# VS Code Microsoft C/C++ Extension showing errors on usual includes

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging

I have this problem since a couple of hours and I can't fix it :

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (D:\\Bureau\\c++\\2\\tower.cpp).
```

And i have this message while passing my cursor on this `#include <iostream>` :
cannot open source file "iostream"

Is there a method to fix this (not just modifying a vscode file every time I open the app) ?

Thanks

Checked that the MINGW path is write and it is good, plus working in bash with --version

Comment: show `c_cpp_properties.json` for a [mre] and tell us where things are in your environment

Comment: `{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "D:/Téléchargements/Autre/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}` my c_cpp file

Comment: D:/Téléchargements/Autre/MinGW/bin/g++.exe is the good repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to put this path to my includePath, for some reasons it was another one.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\Hostx64\x64
```